# App Store update shows different account

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update, accounts

I have a new app update I cannot install. When I review my installed user I see my `@mac.com` address. When attempting to update Cobook, I'm prompted for my `@gmail.com` account. The strange parts are:

1. I'm clearly not logged in as the `gmail` account
2. The `gmail` address is configured as a verified alternative ID

[image: from App Store account]
[image: Login prompt]

I'm running OS X 10.10.1 which was upgraded from 10.9 through the beta up to here. I see a [separate issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57202/being-asked-to-log-in-to-a-different-account-to-update-mac-app-store-apps) on lion that doesn't address my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are being prompted for another Apple ID when trying to download and update that means the app was originally purchased (downloaded) with that email address it is prompting you for.

In order to fix this, you must either continue to enter the password for the @gmail.com account to download future updates or re-purchase the application under your @mac.com email address.

Comment: nice :) and here you go +

Comment: That would make sense, though as I mention the gmail address is associated with my main account. I've attempted the reset password sequence a few times but never receive an email on either account. How do I properly "remove" the app so I can redownload? Would AppCleaner get it all?

Comment: Drag the app from your computer to the Trash (Delete from Applications folder) and make sure you are signed into your newer email address in the App Store. Download and you are good to go.

Comment: That's interesting - I didn't realize the App Store was directly correlated to the fils in `~/Applications/`. I followed these steps and found it did the trick without removing my data. Thanks.